# How to set header in request for HAProxy based on script output?

Tags: load-balancing, authentication, haproxy, http-headers

I have haproxy which runs fine, but we have backend, which validate token against our identity service.

I want to move that logic to HAProxy, where we can run some python or sh script, and get the user name and its ldap groups.

Then we don't have to check for token in each services. We just have to check it the user request has that username and ldapgroup headers or not. If its not, backend will not server the request.

I was checking on google, found some leads like there is [`add-header` and `set-header`](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/aloha/latest/traffic-management/lb-layer7/http-rewrite/) to update the headers info in request or response.

I also found the [`external_check`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#4.2-external-check%20command) which will execute script and take decision.

What I am looking for is combination of `add-header`/`set-header` and `external-check`? Where it will execute the script and set the headers.

Comment: `external_check` allows for a custom _health check_ only. If it fails the backend is taken out as unhealthy.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton, I am looking to set some headers based on some script, is there any way to do that ?